# installing key touch on xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I am trying to install key touch on Xubuntu ."sudo apt-get install keytouch" doesn't work as I get 'Unable to locate package keytouch' message. 
I downloaded the software from http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/
extracted it to my desktop.Opened a terminal in that directory and ran sudo make install , which resulted in below error messages and no installation. Any help is appreciated.Regards.

```
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/gokturk/Desktop/keyTouch-1.1/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\"  -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local/share/locale"\"  -DXTHREADS -D_REENTRANT -DXUSE_MTSAFE_API -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2/freetype2/config -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include      -g -O2 -c main.c
main.c:10:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:253: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gokturk/Desktop/keyTouch-1.1/src'
Makefile:164: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, always get a `.deb` file from the creators of software instead of source code. They work with Xubuntu as well.

It just so happens there is a `.deb` file:

1. Go to the [keyTouch download page](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/dl-keytouch.php).
2. Download either the i386 or AMD64 Ubuntu packages.
3. Open a terminal.
4. `cd` to the directory you downloaded it into.
5. Run `sudo dpkg -i keytouch*.deb`.
6. If it gives you trouble, try `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: I downloaded the i386 version as you suggested and it worked.Thanks again.